# Deleting Rows (physically) from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, delete-row

The problem is that when you hit delete even though the rows are removed from view, still remain, if you check on `Rows.Count`.

The same happens also at `DataTables` with '`Delete(DataRow)`', something I jumped using Remove/RemoveAt.

So after I delete rows from a `DataGridView`, if I take the `DataSource` as `DataTable` and try to export it (in csv in this case) throws a message that it can't obtain info of the deleted rows (paraphrasing - sorry debugger's throw at native language).

I can think of a few tricky ways to play around with `DataGridViewRowCollection`, `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` and `DataTables`, but I really need something more solid and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is on the DataRowState.
In order to get rid of all hand deleted rows you have to do something like this:

```
DataTable t = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

for (int i = t.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (t.Rows[i].RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
           t.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game here, but this is extremely easy.

First, create your DataTable using the WithEvents keyword:

```
Dim WithEvents theDataTable As New DataTable
```

Or you can use the AddHandler method:

```
AddHandler theDataTable.RowDeleted, AddressOf theDataTable_RowDeleted
```

Then handle the RowDeleted Event:

```
Private Sub theDataTable_RowDeleted(sender As Object, e As DataRowChangeEventArgs) Handles theDataTable.RowDeleted
        theDataTable.Rows.Remove(e.Row)
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.